# Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [any, Campaign[]]) => void'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Hi I am recieving a typescript error in my code . following is my code .

```
combineLatest(
          this.translateService.get('CLONE_FLIGHT', { item: this.flight.name}),
          this.flightsService.getCampaignsToClone(this.flight.id)
        ).subscribe([  header, campaigns]) => { 
          console.log('test');
        });
```

the error i am receiving is

```
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [any, Campaign[]]) => void'.
  Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: [any, Campaign[]]): void'.ts(2345)
Cannot find name 'campaigns'.ts(2304)
```

the method signature for translateService.get is as following

```
get(key: string | Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): Observable<string | any>;
```

the method call flightsService.getCampaignsToClone(this.flight.id)

is

```
getCampaignsToClone(flightId: string){
    let campaigns: Campaign[] = [
      {  id:"1", name: "test campaign 001", createdOn:"",lastUpdated: "", createdBy: null,
      type:null, status: null, startDate: null, endDate: null, budget: null, description: "",
      account: null },
      {  id:"2", name: "test campaign 002", createdOn:"",lastUpdated: "", createdBy: null,
      type:null, status: null, startDate: null, endDate: null, budget: null, description: "",
      account: null },
      {  id:"3", name: "test campaign 003", createdOn:"",lastUpdated: "", createdBy: null,
      type:null, status: null, startDate: null, endDate: null, budget: null, description: "",
      account: null }
     ];
    return Observable.of(campaigns);

  }
```

the I code wants to achieve is first resolve the property 'CLONE_FLIGHT' &  loads campaigns objects, then in the subscribe i want to call a modal dialog box. However i am getting the above error
i am newbie to typescript and observables.

appreciate any help
thank you so much
prasanth

Answer (score 1):

it was syntax problem
i should have written like this

```
combineLatest(
  this.translateService.get('CLONE_FLIGHT', { item: this.flight.name}),
  this.flightsService.getCampaignsToClone(this.flight.id)
).subscribe( ([header, campaigns]) => { 
  console.log(header);
});
```